# Игнорирование суб-домена forum.my-site Django

Tags: python, django, nginx

У меня есть два сайта - основной(работает на `Django`) и форум (работает на `XenForo`). я столкнулся с проблемой, что django думает, что `forum.my-site.com/index.php` как-то относится к нему и выдает ошибку "Page not found (`forum.my-site.com/index.php`)". Можно ли как-то игнорировать этот путь?
Сайты лежат на сервере(`Nginx -> uwsgi -> django/python` - это для django, сам форум на php)
`nginx/django.conf`

```
upstream django {
    server unix:///home/my-site/django.sock;
}

server {
    server_name my-site.com www.my-site.com
    charset utf-8;

    client_max_body_size 75M;
    location /media {
        alias /home/my-site/media;
    }
    location /static {
        alias /home/my-site/static;
    }
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass django;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        include /home/my-site/uwsgi_params;
    }
```

`nginx/forum.conf`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name     forum.my-site.com;

    root    /var/www/html;
    index   index.php index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$uri&$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include         fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Comment: `server_name my-site.com www.my-site.com` — вы в этой строке случайно не забыли точку с запятой? (А ещё в этой секции server почему-то ни одного listen нету)

Comment: @andreymal нет, там через пробел. Добавил listen, но теперь 502 ошибка. Изменил `nginx/forum.conf`

Comment: @andreymal все почитнил, не корректный путь к php7.4-fpm.sock указал ‍♂️

Comment: Через пробел это хорошо, но в конце значений всех настроек обязательно должна стоять точка с запятой, которой у вас почему-то нет (возможно, случайно стёрли при вставке в вопрос?)

Comment: @andreymal, скорее всего случайно ибо только что проверял файлы то все ок